# Vim delete lines that contain word A but not word B

Tags: vim, regex

In vim I need to find all lines that contain one word, but do NOT contain another word and delete them.

I've seen plenty of :g, :g! and :v talk while trying to figure this out but nothing that gives me what I need since it appears I need to combine both :g and :v.

If there's not a way to do it in vim is there another suitably easy way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
:v/another/s/^.*word.*\n//
```

should do the trick.

Based on the comment - well, it works for me:

```
=$ cat sample.txt 
word
another
word another

=$ vim -c ":v/another/s/^.*word.*\n//" -c ":wq" sample.txt 

=$ cat sample.txt 
another
word another
```

As you can see lines with "word" have been removed, but not if "another" was in the same line.

Comment: didn't work. Appears to have matched the lines containing 'word' and not taken 'another' into consideration at all.

Comment: Another is meant to protect line from deletion. Clearly, it works.